# Punch-card computers running today

Tags: history

Are there any systems that operate primarily by punch cards (loading/saving data) in production usage today? (Or at least up to the year 2000?)

Comment: I seriously doubt it. This historical question somewhat stretches the boundary of topicality for this site.

Comment: Not primarily but [some](https://www.verifiedvoting.org/resources/voting-equipment/ess/votamatic/).

Comment: I don't think that "are people still using hardware X" is a question about computer science. It's probably on-topic at [retrocomputing.se].